# How to increase NLog log level at runtime

Tags: c#, debugging, runtime, nlog, log-level

My application has too much `log.Trace()` at the beginning of the program, causing the program to malfunction, so I can't use general `NLog` configuration to increase the log level.

So, I would like to increase the log level at runtime. For that, I've found something like this on the internet:

```
foreach (var rule in LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules)
{
    // Iterate over all levels up to and including the target, (re)enabling them.
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        rule.EnableLoggingForLevel(LogLevel.FromOrdinal(i));
    }
}
```

This, however, seems not to be working as the following line does not show up in the logs, although I'm sure this line has been passed:

```
log.Trace("log trace works!");
```

Does anybody know a way to make sure that, from a certain moment in my source code, I can see `log.Trace()` results?

For your information:

1. `log` is defined as `private static readonly Logger log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();`.
2. I've been looking for an `nlog.*` file, containing an `<nlog>` tag, I didn't find anything.

**Edit:**
I'm working with `NLog` version 4.5.4.

**Edit2 (try to force reading of configuration):**
I've modified the `nlog.config` file as follows:

```xml
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" autoReload="true">

    <variable name="myLevel" value="Trace" />
    <rules>
      <logger minLevel="${var:myLevel}" />
    </rules>
    ...
```

Then I tried to force the re-reading of that configuration, as follows:

```
NLog.LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromFile("C:\\...\\NLog.config");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of updating all LoggingRules, then you could consider using NLog Layout in the Level-configuration. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages#semi-dynamic-routing-rules

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Calling `LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers()` after the loop seems to work for me.

Config

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="console" />
```

Code

```
logger.Trace("Trace 1");
logger.Info("Info 1");

foreach (var rule in LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules)
{
    for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        rule.EnableLoggingForLevel(LogLevel.FromOrdinal(i));
    }
}

LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();

logger.Trace("Trace 2"); // This is now printed.
logger.Info("Info 2");
```

Comment: For me EnableLoggingForLevel doesn't work, but SetLoggingLevels do the job :)